# Get checked Radio Button and Selected Drop down values using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Radio Buttons for Gender and Drop down for Courses,

I have Dynamic values in Jquery.

How can I get the selected options in both Gender  and  Courses.

Here is my [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fTtmv/6/)

I am providing my Code here too:

**HTML:**

```
Male <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="1"> - 

Female <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="2"> 

<br>

<select name="courses" id="courses">
    <option value="0">Choose Courses</option>
    <option value="1">PHP</option>
    <option value="2">Jquery</option>
    <option value="3">HTML</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    //these are the values I got, these values are dynamic
    var gender = 2;
    var course = 3; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

Html:

```
Male <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="1" class="gender"/>         
Female <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="2" class="gender"/>
```

Script:
**SET:**

```
 var gender = 2;
 var course = 3;     
 $(".gender").val(gender).prop('checked', true);
 //$(".gender").val(gender).attr('checked', true);
 $("#courses").val(course);
```

**GET:**

```
 $(".gender:checked").val();
 $("#courses").val();
```

Change event:

```
$(".gender,#courses").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Demo:
**[Select radio using class](http://jsfiddle.net/fTtmv/22/)**.

**[Select radio by name](http://jsfiddle.net/fTtmv/20/)**.

**[With change event](http://jsfiddle.net/fTtmv/25/)**.

**[Using attr instead of prop](http://jsfiddle.net/fTtmv/28/)**.

Comment: Prop is a new function. And i m using lod library of Jquwey, what is the alternate of prop ? Can u do it with out Prop

Comment: `attr` is the alternate for `prop`. I've updated my answer check the demo.

Answer (score 2):

**GET**

```
$("input[type='radio']").val();// get radio box value
$("#courses").val();// get dropdown with id "courses value
```

**SET**

```
$("input[type='radio'][value=2]").attr("checked","checked");// set radio box value with checked propety
$("#courses").val(3);// set dropdown with id "courses value
```

**you can also get value when you change value by**

```
$("input[type='radio'],#courses").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

SEE **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fTtmv/13/)**

Comment: No no i dont want values, i want to make it selected using Jquery.

Comment: Radio is not selected

Comment: Can you do the same with radio on Id bases ? cz i have multiple radios

Comment: @Code Hunter Id must be unique for html elements, use the `name` property or add a `class` to the radio buttons and select them by using that class.

Comment: Can you do it with name or class ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var gender = 2;
var course = 3;

$('input:radio').eq(gender-1).prop('checked', true);

$('select').val(course);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var gender = 2;
var course = 3;

$('input:radio[name="gender"]').filter('[value="' + gender + '"]').attr('checked', true);
$("#courses").val(course);
```